# Django: ModelMultipleChoiceField get Bound field value display name in form clean

Tags: django

Is it possible to get the display value for each option in a ModelMultipleChoiceField in it's clean method?

Given the following clean on field tagsUser:

```
def clean_tagsUser(self):
    tu = self.cleaned_data['tagsUser']
    data = self['tagsUser']
    print 'data:', data
    return tu
```

I get the following output:

```
data: <select multiple="multiple" name="tagsUser">
<option value="9" selected="selected">test 1</option>
<option value="20">test 2</option>
<option value="105">test 3</option>
<option value="373" selected="selected">test 4</option>
```

Modifying data = self['tagsUser'].values() returns all the values for each selected option:

```
data: [u'9', u'373']
```

I need to get the display values of each option so that the output for data would be:

```
data: [u'test 1', u'test 2', u'test 3', u'test 4']
```

I found this https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10427 whcih seems to suggest that data = self['tagsUser'].display_value would do what i want. However, display_value does not seem to be implemented as of yet.

Temporary solution:

```
data = self['tagsUser']
data_list = re.findall(r'<.*?>(.+?)<.*?>', str(data))
```

Comment: How is the display value generated?

Comment: It is generated by a ModelMultipleChoiceField with a query to django-taggit. https://github.com/alex/django-taggit/tree/master/docs